# Using blktrace tool

Tags: performance, benchmarking, blktrace

I'm using the blktrace tool to measure the input performance of the write and rewrite. The blktrace produces many files during the write. Do I need to merge all the files into a single file to give it to the blkparse to produce the readable format of the output.

Comment: Whhy is this downvoted. May be the person downvoted can give the reason why so.

Comment: How do you start the blktrace? What is the task you are measuring?

Answer (score 0):

By running blktrace as root

```
blktrace /dev/sda
```

after pressing **Cntrl+c**, blktrace will generate a set of files

[sda.blktrace.0, sda.blktrace.1, ..., sda.blktrace.(Ncpus-1)]

according to the number of cpus your OS can see. To parse the files, you can use blkparse for all files simultaneously

```
blkparse sda.blktrace.0 sda.blktrace.1 ... sda.blktrace.(Ncpus-1)
```

or

```
blkparse sda.blktrace.*
```

Hope it helps.